# Azure Easy Tables storing list<t> in database

Tags: c#, database, azure, azure-sql-database, relationship

I'm trying to store a list of Employee in the Azure database.

I have

**`Employee.cs`**

```
public class Employee {[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
public string Id { get; set; }

[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name")]
public string Name { get; set; }}
```

and

**`Employeer.cs`**

```
public class Employeer{[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
public string Id { get; set; }

[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "employees")]
public ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }}
```

What should I do to store it properly?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Would you like to maintain relationships between Employee and Employeer tables? Have you tried to store ``Employeer_Id`` in your Employee table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm trying to store a list of Employee in the Azure database.

If it is 1:many relationships between Employeer and Employee tables, I recommend that you could maintain and store `Employeer_Id` in your Employee table. If it is many:many relationships between two tables, you could try to maintain `EmployeerIds` in Employee table and store the serialized list of Employeer Ids when you add new Employee entity. The Employee table schema may look like this.

[image]

And we could know retrieve employee info and get EmployeerIds via call API.

[image]